# Is C++ enough for Nokia developing?

Tags: c++, qt, command, nokia

I really need info about Nokia developing. Can I program Nokia (Symbian) devices only with C++, or I need Qt too? (I have Nokia Qt SDK). I'm not really sure about GUI programing, so I ask for help :)

Also it would be really helpful, if you could tell me how to make something like cmd-style on Nokia (Symbian) <--(this is an optional question)

Comment: You will learn to love Qt, I promise

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are probably multiple ways to accomplish what you're trying to write (as Bala.C pointed out, you can use java), but the latest releases of the symbian OS have really encouraged people to write with Qt and specific with QML.  That will likely have the fastest and smoothest interface to the device, because they've spent a fair amount of time optimizing it for the platform.  Plus it'll make your application more portable to their N9 and other Qt based phones (the yet-to-ship non-windows Lumia).

I'm sure there is likely an API to tie directly into their lower-level architecture for drawing on the screen as well, but I suspect it's both not-well documented (unlike Qt) and subject to change from release to release as they don't expect developers to be using it as much.

Comment: Hi, so I need to learn Qt and "QML"? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well, I tried to stay away from "need", but I think you'll be happier in the long run if you do.  But technically you don't "need" to.

Comment: Thanks :) By the way I find Qt pretty hard, and I don't actualy know what is QML :D Looks like I'll need to "study hard" :D Thanks!

Comment: QML is quite a new language and you may or may not like it.  It took me a long time to understand "why" you might want to use QML, but I get it now that I've played with it quite a bit.  Qt, however, is awesome once you get used to the fact that you should use its classes for everything.  Throw STL based stuff away and use the Qt classes instead.  They're much easier to understand than STL, IMHO.  Also, make sure you get the Qt SDK and use QtCreator to edit the code.  It makes finding the right function to call much easier through its auto-type support.

Comment: Thanks, I have Qt SDK, and have setup'ed my Nokia N8 to it :) Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Well, I don't think only C++ will do, but with Java it will be great.

Please go through the following link, it could help you equip yourself for Nokia Symbian Development.

http://www.developer.nokia.com/Develop/Web/Web_runtime.xhtml

Good luck

Comment: Thanks, but I want to use C++ as primary, because of the stability.
In the link as I can see there is no C++, but CSS(i cant develop it), HTML, JavaScript(I cant develop it too). And its more like Web developing languages...   Im really new to programing, and know only FEW things in C++ like std::cout, std::cin, strings, float, int, const... I want to learn developing Nokia, but with C++ and something else if I must.